# Verify if solr reload core is successful or not

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solrcloud

I have a Solr setup with multiple solr collections/Cores. I want to reload a core and verify if the core reload was successful or not. How do I verify is core reload was successful or not?

I send the below request to reload the core.

```
http://hostname:7090/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0&wt=json
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a blocking call. So just wait for the reply and see the status code in the response header.